# VBA - Create Table from WebPage - almost there

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Hope all is well! I checked other posts but I just can't extract the MP3 URLs (I can see them in the debug print). I'm aware that they end in ".href" but however I slice macro won't even reach completion..

Please note I've enabled Microsoft XML v6.0 & HTML Object library

```
Sub FETCHER()

Dim xmlHttp As Object
Dim TR_col As Object, Tr As Object
Dim TD_col As Object, Td As Object
Dim row As Long, col As Long

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    myURL = "https://www.zophar.net/music/nintendo-64-usf/1080-Snowboarding"

    xmlHttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlHttp.send

    Dim html As Object
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText

    Dim tbl As Object
    Set tbl = html.getElementById("tracklist")

    row = 1
    col = 1

    Set TR_col = html.getElementsByTagName("TR")
    For Each Tr In TR_col
        Set TD_col = Tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")
        For Each Td In TD_col
            Cells(row, col) = Td.innerText
            '.href reference would go here-------
            col = col + 1
        Next
        col = 1
        row = row + 1
    Next

End Sub

--
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to work off `tbl`, correctly place your increments for row and col, and finally, there are numerous methods to determine when to access `href`, the best, IMO in this scenario, is to use a test of classname of the `td` as both `tds` with child `a` tags have the same classname.

```
Public Sub FETCHER()
    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Dim TR_col As Object, Tr As Object
    Dim TD_col As Object, Td As Object
    Dim row As Long, col As Long

    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    myURL = "https://www.zophar.net/music/nintendo-64-usf/1080-Snowboarding"

    xmlHttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    xmlHttp.send

    Dim html As Object, tbl As Object
    
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText
    Set tbl = html.getElementById("tracklist")
    Set TR_col = tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")
     
    row = 1
    
    For Each Tr In TR_col
        
        col = 1
        
        Set TD_col = Tr.getElementsByTagName("TD")
        
        For Each Td In TD_col

            If Td.className = "download" Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col) = Td.Children(0).href
            Else
                ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col) = Td.innerText
            End If
            
            col = col + 1
            
        Next
        
        row = row + 1
        
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: ..such a nice  and clean code :) Thanks for your help and I learned something in the process :p